# How to allow will add image using pdfjs?

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am trying to add an image on my canvas using pdfJS, but i am getting an error
"Invalid PDF structure"

Can pdfJS add images like pdfs?

My code:

https://gist.github.com/kamil161g/0a4c5b6eec3f42a3c13877110b6268b4

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, Kamil Gąsior.

In future questions, please add example source codes directly to your question, and don't link to it.

Assuming you are refering to this pdf.js: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

The page clearly states "A general-purpose, web standards-based platform for parsing and rendering PDFs.". This would imply: "no". This is also consistent with the error message you're getting.